# How to parse HTML using PHP4

Tags: php, parsing

I'm writing a site on a server that only has PHP4. I am trying to parse my school's website to get course meeting times and locations ([this website](http://www.brandeis.edu/registrar/schedule/classes/2012/Fall/100/UGRD)). No, I cannot get the administrator to install PHP5.  Here's my code that returns an error:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
   echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

Is javascript an option for this type of task?

Comment: Check this question out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503276/porting-php5-to-legacy-php4-domdocument-quibbles

Comment: could be an use for [php4-html-dom](http://php4-html-dom.sourceforge.net/documentation/php4-html-dom/htmlParser.html)?

Comment: @brad thanks, but i'm new to php parsing.  perhaps you could write an answer on how to use php5 code on a  php4 server

Comment: @user176105, Check out eljunior's link... that looks like a solid direction to investigate.  If you have specific questions on how to use it, you should give it a try and post those specific questions separately.

Comment: Unless you're stuck with using the server, you can achieve what you want to do using PHP5 on a different machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with jQuery:

1.Get the content of the page with PHP
2.Print it in a `div`

```
<?php
echo "<div id='imgSrc'><ul></ul></div>";
echo "<div id='scrapperContent' style='display:none'>";
echo file_get_contents($url);
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Now add the next code above the php code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("img").each(function (i) {
        $('#imgSrc ul').append("<li>" + $(this).attr("src") + "</li>");
      });
});
</script>
```

As you can see , it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Sv33T/

However , I've just noticed that there is no use of `<img>` in your school's website at all.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the syntax from [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), which only supports PHP 5+.

According to the site, the package was inspired by Jose Solorzano's [HTML Parser for PHP 4](http://php-html.sourceforge.net/). So it might help for you to check that out.